# Is there ever an example of when the union of a space $X$ and a collection of compact subspaces is not compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I have seen several examples where the union of a space $X$ and collection of compact subspaces is compact.  Is there ever an example of when the union of a space $X$ and a collection of compact subspaces is not compact?

Answer (score 3):

The phrasing makes it somewhat hard to tell what is being asked; the union of a space $X$ with any of its subspaces is always $X$.  I'll try to respond to the spirit of the question.

It is true in general that a *finite* union of compact spaces is compact.  (As a side note: it is not always true that a finite *intersection* of compact spaces is compact, but it is often true—for example, it is true whenever the ambient space is Hausdorff.)

On the other hand, it is very much not the case that an *infinite* union of compact spaces is compact.  For example: any point is compact, but any space at all is a union of points.  So only very special unions of compact spaces can hope to be compact.

Comment: @bof Good point.  I knew this, but justified my statement with some bizarre circular reasoning.  Anyway, I've corrected the statement.